# Control + , in Terminal.app

Tags: bash, emacs, terminal

I use the shortcut `C-,` with the window version of emacs.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-,") 'dabbrev-expand)
```

My problem is that this shortcut does not work in the console version of emacs.

I've tried many things (`.inputrc`, `set bind-tty-special-chars off`, `bind` command in `.bashrc`) but nothing seems to work; I never manage to receive something with this combination of keys.

I've managed to bind other non standards shortcuts like `Ctrl-<left-arrow>`.

Answer (score 2):

Control-Comma does not map to a control character in the system keyboard map. Therefore, it is sent to applications as just a comma. Terminal then sends this comma to the tty, where Emacs receives it. If you want Control-Comma to map to a control character or other sequence that Emacs can distinguish from a normal comma, you'll have to alter the system keyboard map. Doing so is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Do you any clue for the best way to "alter the system keyboard map" on MacOSX