# Why can't I set mark on emacs?

Tags: emacs, windows-8, console, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to run Emacs on a guest system (Ubuntu 12.04)

inside a Windows 8 command console.

This is done through vagrant + Virtual box.

It looks like this,

Guest system : Ubuntu 12.04

Host system  : Windows 8

Environment  : Virtual Box + Vagrant

[image]

Emacs works fine except I can not set mark on text (C-SPC).

I supposed there is some kind conflict with the key binding.

So I tried and added this to init.el,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-8")   'set-mark-command)
```

It doesn't work either.

Would someone please advice me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Emacs in a terminal, then `C-SPC` and `C-8` are [unlikely to send what you want them to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110801/why-does-ctrl-not-work-when-i-bind-it-as-a-command-in-emacs/11118511#11118511).

Use `C-h c C-SPC` to ask Emacs what it's seeing.

Try using `C-@` instead.

FYI, I found the Cygwin X server excellent for running GUI Emacs in a Windows-hosted VM. With GUI Emacs you can use many more key combinations than a terminal emulator will permit.

If you try that, start the server with `startxwin` rather than `startx` (the former enables the X server's windows to appear as regular Windows windows), and then connect from an xterm with `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` (see the man page) to connect with X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the hint.

I finally figured out what the problem really is.

From the answer @phils, this link clarifies the problem.

*[Why does Ctrl+. not work when I bind it to a command in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110801/why-does-ctrl-not-work-when-i-bind-it-as-a-command-in-emacs/11118511#11118511)*

In my case, all `C-[any other key]` bindings work, except for the set-mark-command.

I found a workaround.

By adding the following code to `.emacs.d\init.el` I can use F8 to set mark now.

```
(global-set-key [f8] (quote set-mark-command))
```

It is still confusing why in other command, Ctrl+key bindings works.

Comment: I think I know the answer for your confusion. By typing @, you need Shift key, but Ctrl+Shift is reserved by Windows for switch language input method.