# How to type commands that need shift key in emacs? (e.g. M-< M-> C-?)

Tags: emacs, shift, typing

I am ultimate beginner in emacs.. How to type commands that need shift key? For example: to type M-> i need to type "Meta key(Alt)" + "shift" + "." Hope I was clear.. I use US keyboard layout. All the best..

Comment: From other comments it sounds like there's some keyboard confusion, but if you're running Emacs in a [Terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11118511/324105) I suggest running it in GUI mode instead, to eliminate that as a compounding cause of confusion (at least until the initial problem is resolved).

Comment: To add to what others have said: You need to find out what Emacs sees when you do `M-<` (when you hold Alt and Shift and hit the key labeled `<`).  For that, use `C-h k` and then `M-<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get M-> type first the "Alt" key and then the "Shift" key and the "." key **at the same time**.

Answer (score 0):

You press those keys as a chord, just like shift-alt-.  You can also use Esc as a synonym for the meta key if you prefer that.

Comment: I doing that non stop and nothing happens.. It prints "Eval:" in the bottom of the terminal and I should type something..

Comment: Sounds like you *don't* have a US keyboard. Shift-. is : on many European keyboards; M-: is `eval-expression`.

Comment: You can use Esc as Meta, but it's important to note the difference in how it is used: `M-x` can be entered by *holding* Alt and pressing X, or by pressing Esc *and releasing it*, *then* pressing X.

Comment: You can get away from the `Eval:` prompt with C-g (and generally cancel most things in Emacs that way).

Comment: @user3788088 Perhaps your input method doesn't match your keyboard. That happens to me often when I accidentally switch to Swedish.