# Why doesn't emacs org mode work in -nw (--no-window-system) mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to give a shot to emacs org mode, so I created a file and started adding bullets and tasks, all fine.

I'd love to use emacs in -nw mode so it would blend into my workflow, but, when I open an org file in -nw mode, it read the bullets, but I can't use any of the org mode shortcuts and I get none of its benefits. Already double checked if I was indeed in org mode.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Works for me. Does any other mode work for you? What terminal do you use?

Comment: Only works if I open it without the -nw parameter. I use terminator.

Comment: Many org-mode key bindings are ones that are hard to transmit through a terminal. See, for example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11118511/113848), [this answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13957/11), and [this answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/989/11). Though I would expect the `TAB` key to work correctly.

Comment: as @legoscia said, it is a problem with keybindings. alt+RET didn' work but esc+RET did.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your terminal is intercepting your keystrokes, and you should go into its settings to change that. If you're using Terminal for OSX, go to Preferences, and under the Profiles tab, select your profile and then the Keyboard tab. At the bottom there are two check boxes, and you just need to check "Use Option as Meta Key"