# How to Remap org-mode keybindings?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664764/why-doesnt-emacs-org-mode-work-in-nw-no-window-system-mode?noredirect=1#comment62828150_37664764), I can not use org mode properly within tmux. So, I would want to remap keybindings like `alt+RET` for creating a new bullet item or `shift + left/right arrow` to change an item hierarchy.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`org-insert-heading` is bound to `M-<RET>` by default, you just need to remap it

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-<RET>") nil) ; remove old binding
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c n") 'org-insert-heading) ; add new tmux-friendly binding
```