# S-M-* commands aren't recognized by Emacs when it run in iterm2 with command "emacs -nw"

Tags: macos, emacs, iterm2

environment: macos iterm2

S-M-* commands aren't recognized by Emacs when i run it in iterm2 with command "emacs -nw", but it work in emacs(open emacs with command emacs)

i have set option as +ESC in iterm2

https://s2.ax1x.com/2019/04/05/ARGUBV.png

Comment: Some of the links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118511/113848) might help. They show various ways to figure out what iterm2 is sending to Emacs, and how to get Emacs to recognise it.

Comment: thank a lot, it helped